# Do I need to prepare query before get_results(), get_row() and get_var()?

Tags: php, mysql

I know that we don't need to use prepare($query) when we put it in insert() and update() because these functions sanitize data for us but I'm not sure if we need to prepare query before putting it in get_results(), get_row() and get_var()?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your query has no dynamic input, then you technically do not need to use [`$wpdb->prepare()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks), however that assumes your own input is safe.

If your query contains parameters in which are dynamic, especially supplied by users from a form as an example, then you will want to use [`$wpdb->prepare()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks).

Using [`$wpdb->prepare()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) is just good practice, but in order to use it, you must pass at least two arguments (the query, and at least one placeholder).

> Please note: As of 3.5, wpdb::prepare() enforces a minimum of 2 arguments.

See: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2012/12/12/php-warning-missing-argument-2-for-wpdb-prepare/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But you please explain to me this. I'm wondering if get_results, get_row, get_var functions do have built-in sanitizing function and we don't need to do extra work to protect the query even it contains dynamic parameters? Or we have to use prepare() all the time with dynamic parameters?

Comment: Nope, they do not call `prepare()` internally, like `insert()` and `update()` do... It's up to you to sanitize data for methods in question.

Comment: So there are 2 methods right?
1. Sanitize data first => No need prepare();
2. Use prepare() with raw data.
Is this correct?

Comment: You can sanitize before passing data to the likes of a method such as `get_results()` but that's what `prepare()` was intended for, doing the sanitization for you. I recommend reading the source for `prepare()` in `wp-includes/wp-db.php` around line 1210 to see exactly what this method does under the hood for you.

Comment: You need a minimum of one placeholder - not two - which after the query, becomes the second argument.  Review the core comments https://make.wordpress.org/core/2012/12/12/php-warning-missing-argument-2-for-wpdb-prepare/ .  This should be edited so it doesn't mislead.

Comment: @BobDiego in the future also ensure to click the "edit" button if you reputation allows, to propose the edit you wish to make with supporting comments.